# Using URL of file as file path in Python in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, url, aws-lambda

I am trying to acquire a file from a url on the web and then open that file for use in an application I’m making in python on AWS Lambda. There doesn’t seem to be a way for me to acquire the file in the form I need it, which I believe to be an os.Pathlike object.

Here is what I am trying now, which doesn’t work since requests.get returns a response not path. I’m posting from a phone right now so I cannot use code tags. Apologies.

filename = requests.get(“url.com/file.txt”)

f = open(filename, ‘rb’)

I have also tried a urlparse and a urllib urlretrieve on the url but that does not return a pathlike object either. Note that I don’t believe I can just use wget or something on the shell level as I am using AWS lambda.

Comment: don't think a get request returns a string, have you tried filename.json() or dir(filename) or filename.content?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
url = 'http://url.com/file.txt'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
f = open(r, ‘rb’)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do such operation, it's always a good to see the entire response of the request you are doing. I usually use the **dict** attribute, works quite often

```
print(response.__dict__)
```

On the ones I have done, there were a _content field in the response object with the file bytes. Then you can simply use the io module to read this file :

```
file = io.BytesIO(response._content)
```

This can then be used as a file just like when you do open() function